# Js frameworks, node js, vue cli

Tags: node.js, vue.js

Hello everyone I am like anyone who wants to learn js framework but when I install vue cli and build any app many errors are blowing up in my face if anyone has advice for me please help me fix this problem Note: My laptop is running windows 7

When i install vue i was think every thing is good

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It is impossible to answer your question without any information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.